# CSS color names + alpha transparency

Tags: css

Is it possible to define a color in CSS by its name plus an alpha transparency value?

I.e.:

```
#mytext { color: red 0.5 }
```

rather than resorting to rgba like

```
#mytext { color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5) }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want this way:

```
#mytext{
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Note that opacity will affect the whole element, not just the text, so for example, if the #mytext element had a background color, that would also receive the opacity value of 0.5

However, I agree with Dai, using color names instead of hex or rgb codes isn't something you should rely on too much. It's an ugly color palette to work with.

Answer (score 8):

#### Yes, this is now possible in vanilla CSS

```css
background-color: color-mix(in srgb, red 30%, transparent);

// Same as above
background-color: color-mix(in srgb, red, transparent 70%);

// 50% is the default
background-color: color-mix(in srgb, red, transparent);

// You can also mix standard colors
background-color: color-mix(in srgb, #ff0000 40%, #00aaff);
```

If you're thinking, "wow, that's the coolest thing ever!" Yes. Yes it is.

#### Runnable snippet

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.a {
  background-color: color-mix(in srgb, red 30%, transparent);
}
.b {
  background-color: color-mix(in srgb, red, transparent 70%);
}
.c {
  background-color: color-mix(in srgb, red, transparent);
}
.d {
  background-color: color-mix(in srgb, #ff0000 40%, #00aaff);
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
<div class="d"></div>
```

**Documentation**

- [color-mix() | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-mix)

[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_color_color-mix) (supported by major browsers)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
background-color: rgba($scssNamedColor, 0.5);
```

Comment: The question didn't mention SCSS but CSS only.

Answer (score 1):

## No

Though there is such method in sass, prefer converting to hex digit/rgb and then add alpha accordingly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).