# Set CSS color using color text name like "red" and also set opacity?

Tags: css

Is there a way to set a **CSS** color using a **color text name** and also set opacity?

Something like:

`color: lightgray alpha 0.5`

Or do I have to use RGBalpha, like:

`color: rgba(211,211,211,0.3)`

Comment: look up `rgba`?

Comment: you have to use rgba or an extra layer where you can set color and opacity

Comment: You can specify an opacity property in CSS, but this will give the whole div the same opacity. RGBA is a better way and gives you more control.

Comment: No there isn't currently a way to do that

Comment: I've edited the question. It was saying rgb, where it should have been saying rgba. It works with `rgba` but sometimes I want to use regular color text names instead of looking up the rgb code for "lightgray", for example.

Comment: Well, if you're open to using SCSS or SASS, you can store these values as variables.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492695/css-color-names-alpha-transparency

Comment: use SASS, there is a way to define a color name and apply an opacity

Comment: Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492695/css-color-names-alpha-transparency

Comment: @Babatope.Festus thanks! That's exactly my question. But the OP there accepted a very bad answer IMO.

Comment: if you go the sass route: https://www.quackit.com/css/css_color_codes.cfm will help with your list of colours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the [MDN documentation on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/color) tells us, you should be using `rgba(r,g,b,a)` or even `hsla(h,s,l,a)` if you want to pick a color with alpha. So it is not possible to do what you were trying to achieve using the first way you showed.

Answer (score 1):

**It's not possible** to combine color text names and alpha.

---

You can handle your problems two ways

**Advised:** Translate the color text name to rgb so `lightgray` = `211,211,211`

```
span.lightgray {
   color: rgba(211,211,211, 0.3); // Your own suggestion
}
```

**Not advised:** Use the color text name and opacity, but opacity applies to the entire element (so background or other properties will also be transparent/affected)

```
span.lightgray{
   color: lightgray;
   opacity: 0.3; // Not advised
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `opacity`.

But this will affect both `background-color` and `color`.

```css
#txt {
  color: red;
  background-color: lime;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<span id="txt">TEST</span>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use RGBalpha or HSL or HSLA.

eg:
1) RGBA:
rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
red-255
gree-0
blue-0
aplha(opaque or transperant)-0.2

2) HSL:
hsl(120, 100%, 50%)
Hue is the degree of colour in the wheel - 120.
Saturation - 100%
Lightness - 50%

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_colors.asp

We can also use the opacity property like

```
div {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

But opacity property will add transparency to the background. so all the child element will become transparent. So it might be difficult to read. So it is better to use HSL or RGBA

Comment: I don't see any color name